# Unable to screw completely into plug/anchor

Tags: concrete, mounting, anchor, curtain-rail

I am attaching [curtain rail holders](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/tools-fittings-curtain-rails/curtain-rods-rails/betydlig-wall-ceiling-bracket-black-art-60217228/) into a wall for installing a door curtain.  I have drilled four holes (two for each bracket) with diameter 6 mm and depth 50 mm, in a wall which appears to have ~12 mm plaster followed by brick or concrete (I was only able to continue drilling beyond 12 mm with a hammer drill).  I bought [these anchors](http://www.homebase.co.uk/en/homebaseuk/stanley-25-x-multi-fixing-hammer-in-6-x-40mm---stf36425-xj-166564) into the hole, but when I try to insert the screws, the first bit works fine but I am unable to screw them in completely; as I progress there is more and more force required to continue screwing, but for the last 5 mm I am damaging the head rather than making the screw enter.  When I insert the screw into the anchor outside the wall, it goes in almost completely but breaks open the end of the anchor and widens it.  Inside the wall there is no space for it to do so; I suspect this is why I can't strew them in completely?  The anchor package illustrates a hammer (apparently it is a "hammer-in plug") but part of the curtain rail holder is in the way, so we can't completely hammer it in either.

Do I have the right anchors/plugs and screws for this job?  Initially I had the hole 6 mm wide and 40 mm deep.  Based on advice I deepened it, now it is 6 mm wide and 50 mm deep.  Does it need to be wider than 6 mm?

[image: Mounting with plug and screw]

[image: Wall with plug]

[image: Drillhole]

Dimensions:

- Mounting bracket, inner diameter: 4.81 mm
- Screw cylinder (smooth part): 4.29 mm
- Screw head: 8.8 mm
- Plug: 5.82 mm
- Plug head: 9.32 mm
- Plug with screw inside (outside wall) expands to: 9.2 mm

Comment: Show us some pictures of the hole and the anchors

Comment: It sounds like the drill bit is under sized for the anchor.

Comment: @EdBeal The anchor fits but someone else told me the hole should be deeper than the anchor, we will try that today.

Comment: @JeffCates I have added some photos.

Comment: I'm unclear how your bit is spinning in those screws. Torx screws hold a bit extremely well. Yous should almost break the screw before it strips, unless your holes isn't deep enough. Are you using the correct bit?

Comment: @isherwood The hole now has diameter 6 mm, depth 50 mm.  I don't know if that is correct.

Comment: @isherwood I was screwing manually without a drill bit.

Comment: The holes do need to be deeper that was good advice  to drill deeper.

Comment: What does "screwing manually without a drill bit" mean? How does one turn a screw without a driver bit?

Comment: @isherwood I thought "drill bit" was a part inserted into a drill.  I used a stand-alone screwdriver.  I suppose I am not using the correct terms.

Comment: A "bit" in American English refers to the working end or tip of a tool. I can be a cutting bit, a driving bit, a grinding bit, etc. Obviously you've resolved your issue, but it's easy to use a too-small bit with torx. It'll appear correct even when it's too small. Please accept your answer to close this question.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the language clarification.  I will accept my own answer as soon as I can (in 8 hours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the **wrong kind of plugs/screws**.  The plugs I was using were *hammer-in plugs* and the screws correspondingly.  Those were not designed for the task.

I bought [this package of plugs and screws](http://www.diy.com/departments/bq-metal-plastic-wall-plug-screw-pack-of-50/254286_BQ.prd) instead and now all is good.

[image: Curtain]